# Huge Google firestore data reads

Tags: database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore, profiling

I need a way to do profiling or something that makes me figure out why there are a huge number of data reads in google firestore,
The goal is to know, the source of those reads for example, and similar stuff.

Comment: There are no provided tools.  A common source of unexpected reads is the Firestore console window being left open.  If it's not that, you'll have to build your own way to track the origin of reads.

Comment: Did you figure out what's causing your read quota to explode @Donmoear?